# How to retrieve QuestionAnswer using ASP.NET Membership

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'm wondering if it's possible for me to get the QuestionAnswer field from ASP.NET membership in the same way that you can get the UserName and PasswordQuestion.

```
MembershipUser mu = Membership.GetUser(userId);
string username = mu.UserName;
string question = mu.PasswordQuestion;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty certain that the QuestionAnswer is hashed in the database in the same way that the password is. If that is the case then you won't be able to get the QuestionAnswer in any sort of human-readable format (although if you require the QuestionAnswer in this format you can always run a regular SQL query against the table rather than using the Membership API).

If needed you can always [change the password question and answer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.changepasswordquestionandanswer.aspx)

Hope this helps.